# Is there a way to specify the Parquet Version using AWS data Wrangler

Tags: aws-data-wrangler

We are writing parquet Files which seem to default to version 1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrFsW.png)

which teradata NOS complains with a
"Native Object Store user error: Unsupported file version"

How can we specify with AWS data wrangler /SDK for Pandas the parquet version towrite.

Not sure what to try... maybe need to find alternative writer?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the version using `pyarrow_additional_kwargs`:

```
wr.s3.to_parquet(
    ...
    pyarrow_additional_kwargs={"version":"2.6"}
)
```